# Is there any method in boto3 to pull ecr image

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, amazon-ecr

I have checked boto3 documentation. Doesn't find any method. Can anyone please let me know how can pull image from ecr with python.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, there is no such mathod. [Boto3's ecr](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecr.html) API is for **management actions** of the ECR registry and repository, such as creating new repository.

To actually pull images into your docker from python, you have to use thrid-party [docker python library](https://pypi.org/project/docker/).